# Java/Selenium: Instance of not yet defined class in method

Tags: java, selenium, methods, casting

In Java, it is possible to define a return value T, extending an abstract base class - and in the return method, to cast T into an instance of a specific non-abstract class.

Example: My website is supposed to show a registration page in European countries, and a terms+conditions page elsewhere. I have a test method providing this:

```
public <T extends StartBasePage> T openStartPage(boolean isInEurope) {
        if (isInEurope) {
            return (T) pageProvider.createPageAsserted(StartRegistrationPage.class);
        } else {
            return (T) pageProvider.createPageAsserted(StartTermsPage.class);
        }
    }
```

But is it possible to use T in the method already as an "instance" of abstract StartBasePage and then use methods from that abstract class to define what exactly is supposed to be cast into?

Imagine StartBasePage has a method extracting the country ISO-2 code in which the starting page was opened; and there is a boolean method to check if a country code is from a European country:

```
public <T extends StartBasePage> T openStartPage() {
        if (T.extractCountryFromStartPage().isInEurope()) {
            return (T) pageProvider.createPageAsserted(StartRegistrationPage.class);
        } else {
            return (T) pageProvider.createPageAsserted(StartTermsPage.class);
        }
    }
```

It is not possible as written, but is there an adaption making this possible?

Comment: After accepting the Terms and Conditions, do the non-European countries see the registration page?

Answer (score 1):

The [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) encapsulates behavioral differences like this while keeping the overall interaction the same. The `openStartPage` method should return a TermsAndConditionsPage whether the user is in Europe or elsewhere. There would be a single sub class of TermsAndConditionsPage, named something like NullTermsAndConditionsPage or MissingTermsAndConditionsPage. Calling the `acceptTermsAndConditions()` method should accept the terms and conditions, or simply do nothing. Then both cases should return the StartRegistrationPage.

```
public class TermsAndConditionsPage {
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public TermsAndConditionsPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public StartRegistrationPage acceptTermsAndConditions() {
        // Click the "Accept" button and wait

        return new StartRegistrationPage(driver);
    }
}

public class NullTermsAndConditionsPage extends TermsAndConditionsPage {
    @override
     public StartRegistrationPage acceptTermsAndConditions() {
        return new StartRegistrationPage(driver);
    } 
}
```

Then modify your `openStartPage` method to detect if the user is in Europe and conditionally return either a new TermsAndConditionsPage or a NullTermsAndConditionsPage:

```
public TermsAndConditionsPage openStartPage() {
    if (isInEurope()) {
        return new NullTermsAndConditionsPage(driver);
    } else {
        return new TermsAndConditionsPage(driver);
    }
}
```

Calling and interacting with the `openStartPage` method is normalized between countries that require a ToS and those that do not:

```
StartRegistrationPage = openStartPage().acceptTermsAndConditions();
```

When in Europe, the worse thing that happens is the `NullTermsAndConditionsPage.acceptTermsAndConditions()` method gets called and does absolutely nothing except return the `StartRegistrationPage` object, since in those flows that is the page the user lands on.